# multibyte character

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, oracle

I have loaded multibyte characters(chinese characters) into oracle and from Java i am fetching data from oracle. in eclipse console it showing `?` in place of chinese characters.
This is only happening in windows environment, not in linux.

data inserted in oracle table:

```
 NAME         
 ------------ 
 국            
 subhan       
 汉
```

code used to fetch data:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        String url="dbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))";
        Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url, "OE_schema", "OE_schema");

    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select NAME from MULTIBYTEINFA332115");
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(" "+rs.getString(1));
    }
```

after running code , it showing below results in eclipse console:

```
 ?  
 subhan
 ?
```

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2004/jw-0419-multibytes.html?page=2

Answer (score 3):

The console in Windows is showing a latin character set by default, hence UTF-8 and UTF-16 characters often run into problems.

For your run config, you need to set the encoding in on the common tab for each app you plan to run with a non-default requirement.

Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to eclispe.ini

Comment: I ran System.out.println("Estée Lauder 汉 "); from my Eclipse (under Windows) and this is a copypaste right from console - Estée Lauder 汉